# Ruby on Rails URI::InvalidComponentError keeps crashing server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, uri

My Rails server is repeatedly crashing on certain requests and I am not able to replicate under which conditions it does so. Here is the log entry for the most recent time.

```
I, [2015-07-21T12:10:45.080631 #28576]  INFO -- : Started GET "/" for 209.126.230.71 at 2015-07-21 12:10:45 -0400
F, [2015-07-21T12:10:45.087452 #28576] FATAL -- :
URI::InvalidComponentError (bad component(expected host component): localhost:):
  /home/admin/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/uri/generic.rb:593:in `check_host'
  /home/admin/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/uri/generic.rb:634:in `host='
  actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/redirection.rb:37:in `serve'
  actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/redirection.rb:21:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:51:in `serve'
  actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:43:in `block in serve'
  actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:30:in `each'
  actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:30:in `serve'
  actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:819:in `call'
  rack (1.6.1) lib/rack/etag.rb:24:in `call'
  rack (1.6.1) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call'
  rack (1.6.1) lib/rack/head.rb:13:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:260:in `call'
  rack (1.6.1) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in `context'
  rack (1.6.1) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:560:in `call'
  activerecord (4.2.1) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in `call'
  activerecord (4.2.1) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:649:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:88:in `call'
  activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:88:in `_run_callbacks'
  activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:776:in `_run_call_callbacks'
  activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:78:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
  railties (4.2.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
  railties (4.2.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
  activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
  activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
  railties (4.2.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.6.1) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:22:in `call'
  rack (1.6.1) lib/rack/runtime.rb:18:in `call'
  activesupport (4.2.1) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:28:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:113:in `call'
  rack (1.6.1) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:113:in `call'
  railties (4.2.1) lib/rails/engine.rb:518:in `call'
  railties (4.2.1) lib/rails/application.rb:164:in `call'
  thin (1.6.3) lib/thin/connection.rb:86:in `block in pre_process'
  thin (1.6.3) lib/thin/connection.rb:84:in `catch'
  thin (1.6.3) lib/thin/connection.rb:84:in `pre_process'
  thin (1.6.3) lib/thin/connection.rb:53:in `process'
  thin (1.6.3) lib/thin/connection.rb:39:in `receive_data'
  eventmachine (1.0.7) lib/eventmachine.rb:187:in `run_machine'
  eventmachine (1.0.7) lib/eventmachine.rb:187:in `run'
  thin (1.6.3) lib/thin/backends/base.rb:73:in `start'
  thin (1.6.3) lib/thin/server.rb:162:in `start'
  thin (1.6.3) lib/thin/controllers/controller.rb:87:in `start'
  thin (1.6.3) lib/thin/runner.rb:200:in `run_command'
  thin (1.6.3) lib/thin/runner.rb:156:in `run!'
  thin (1.6.3) bin/thin:6:in `<top (required)>'
  /home/admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@blc_sprint/bin/thin:23:in `load'
  /home/admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@blc_sprint/bin/thin:23:in `<main>'
  /home/admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@blc_sprint/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
  /home/admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@blc_sprint/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
```

I have no idea what is causing this. The vast majority of requests cause no problem.

production.rb:

```
Rails.application.configure do

  config.cache_classes = true

  config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = true

  config.serve_static_files = true # ENV['RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES'].present?

  config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier
  config.assets.digest = true

  config.log_level = :debug
  config.i18n.fallbacks = true

  config.active_support.deprecation = :notify

  config.log_formatter = ::Logger::Formatter.new

  config.active_record.dump_schema_after_migration = false
```

Comment: Could you edit and include the code from your development.rb

Comment: This is in production mode, adding it.

Answer (score 0):

Just Find in your project (with your favorite IDE) `localhost:`. The `host` should be only the host, and not the host with `:` at the end.